# $wpdb->insert() does not Insert record in a table

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb, sql

I'm trying to understand and get hold of the $wpdb global object but can't seem to make it work. Basically, I'm trying to insert a single record into a custom table in wordpress DB. Instead of creating your own connection string and using that, I've seen the Global $wpdb object do the trick for us. I followed the codex example and tried to do it on my own but failed. I don't get any error but the record does not insert as well. It been hours figuring the issue. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
<?php
class Listings{

    private $buisnessName;
    private $contactName;
    private $categories;
    private $websiteURL;
    private $telephoneNum;
    private $address;
    private $socialLinks;
    private $shortDescription;
    private $images;
    private $fullDescription;
    private $tags;

    function __construct($buisnessName, $contactName, $categories, $websiteURL, $telephoneNum,$address,$socialLinks, $shortDescription, $images, $fullDescription,$tags){

        $this->buisnessName = $buisnessName;
        $this->contactName = $contactName;
        $this->categories = $categories;
        $this->websiteURL = $websiteURL;
        $this->telephoneNum = $telephoneNum;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->socialLinks = $socialLinks;
        $this->shortDescription = $shortDescription;
        $this->images = $images;
        $this->fullDescription = $fullDescription;
        $this->tags = $tags;        
    }

    function Insert_Listing(){
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert('wp_listings_info', array("Buisness_Name" => $this->buisnessName,"Contact_Name" => $this->contactName, "Categories" => $this->categories, "Website_URL" => $this->websiteURL, "Telephone_Number" => $this->telephoneNum, "Address" => $this->address, "Social_Network_Links" => $this->socialLinks, "Short_Description" => $this->shortDescription, "Images" => $this->images, "Full_Description" => $this->fullDescription, "Tags" => $this->tags), array("%s", "%s","%s", "%s","%s", "%s","%s", "%s","%s", "%s","%s"));
    }

}
?>
```

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_listings_info` (
`L_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Business_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Contact_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Categories` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Website_URL` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`Telephone_Number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`Social_Network_Links` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`Short_Description` text NOT NULL,
`Images` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Full_Description` text NOT NULL,
`Tags` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`L_ID`)
)
```

and I'm calling the object of the class like this:

```
$listingObj = new Listings($buisnessName, $contactName, $categories, $websiteURL, $telephoneNum,$address, $socialLinks, $shortDescription, $images, $fullDescription,$tags);
$listingObj->Insert_Listing();
```

Again I'm saying that I'm not getting any error at all, It's just the code does not insert the record as well.

**EDIT:**

Ok, After debugging I get this error but 2 records having the same value are inserted each time the script runs. Though Insert function is only being called once.

I get this error:

```
WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'Buisness_Name' in 'field list']
INSERT INTO wp_listings_info ( 
    Buisness_Name, Contact_Name, Categories, Website_URL,
    Telephone_Number, A‌ddress, Social_Network_Links, Short_Description, 
    Images, Full_Description, T‌​ags
) VALUES (
    'My Buisness Name', 'My Buisness Contact Name', 'My Categories',
    'My Website URL','1234567','My Address','My Social Links',
    'My Short Descriptions','My images Path','My Full Description',
    'My Tags comma seperated'
)
```

Comment: [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: Thanks ! I get this error:
WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'Buisness_Name' in 'field list']
INSERT INTO `wp_listings_info` (`Buisness_Name`,`Contact_Name`,`Categories`,`Website_URL`,`Telephone_Number`,`Address`,`Social_Network_Links`,`Short_Description`,`Images`,`Full_Description`,`Tags`) VALUES ('My Buisness Name','My Buisness Contact Name','My Categories','My Website URL','1234567','My Address','My Social Links','My Short Descriptions','My images Path','My Full Description','My Tags comma seperated')

Comment: What error? [Edit] the information into the question. ___Do Not___ post it into a comment.

Comment: Done. But I get another issue. It inserts 2 records of the same value each time I run the script showing the above error.

Comment: Did you notice the typo on the column name? Buisness_Name instead of Business_Name

Comment: @RicardoNuñez
Yes, I've fixed that mistake. But I can't figure out why it is inserting 2 records in my table when it's only called once :/

Comment: I have two people with a similar problem. One guy said that he installed his plugin in two different server and it worked. I'm guessing a version problem. Another one you can see the different test he did. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/insert-into-inserts-duplicate-entries

Comment: Thanks @RicardoNuñez.I've checked out the link and fortunately I came up with the same solution to the problem of not adding duplicates by using a unique identifier on one colum. Though, It's still strange for me to see $wpdb Global object inserting two same records even though it is called once. Strange, Very Strange.

Comment: You're *sure* it's called once? It's not being called in a `for()` or `while()` loop, or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure It's called once. Though I've seen some similar problem happen with people . e.g link mentioned by @RicardoNuñez above !